# Graphing solutions for over-plotted data, faceting, and adding line of best fit

Tags: r, ggplot2

Originally, I was thinking I need two plots - one to plot "Female_life_Growth" vs "Rate_median_income" by "Census Region" and one by if they were a red/blue state (Red_blue). I've been messing with GGPlot but can't figure out a good plot with this complicated of data.

**Update: Here's what I've tried; any way to make this a better visual?**. [image]

**Update: Added faceting. How do I add line of best fit to each?**.
[image]

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(female_life_growth=c(-3.48,-3.48,-3.39,-3.39,-3.17,-3.17,
                                      -2.73,-2.57,-2.57,-2.57,-2.57,-2.51),
                 Red_blue=c('Red','Red','Red','Blue','Red','Blue',
                            'Blue','Red','Blue','Red','Blue','Red'),
                 Rate_median_income=c(33378,45726,31211,20206,29050,33799,
                                      38664,32538,39171,41403,34217,35789),
                 Census_region=c('South','South','South','Midwest','Midwest',
                                 'West','Northeast','West','West','Northeast',
                                 'Midwest','Northeast'))
```

Comment: If you were to post your data using `dput` instead of showing us an image of your data,  we could make graphs that you might consider.   Also, the sample of your data shown in the image has both Red_blue and Census_Region as constants.

Comment: Start with what do you consider to be your independent and dependent variables. Then try plotting attributes of those as colors or shapes. I'll give an example.

Comment: @G5W this is just a sample of 3112 observations of 61 variables. Red_blue has RED and BLUE as values, and Census_Region has South, West, Midwest, and Northeast as values

Comment: Thats @RyanRunge. I'll look for the example, I'm just very unexperienced with ggplot so I don't know all my options and have syntax errors

Comment: @JoeJohnson - I understand. We all start at that same place. I've provided a sample solution below that will hopefully teach a few of the key ggplot tools. You can adapt it how you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Rate_median_income,y=female_life_growth,
                 col=Red_blue,shape=Census_region),size=2.5) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("Blue","Red"),values=c("blue","red")) +
  xlab("Rate Median Income") +
  ylab("Female Life Growth") +
  guides(shape=guide_legend("Census Region"),
         col=guide_legend("Political Leaning\nof State"))
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT: In case of over-plotting, try faceting the data:**

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Rate_median_income,y=female_life_growth,
                 col=Red_blue,shape=Census_region),size=2.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Census_region) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("Blue","Red"),values=c("blue","red")) +
  xlab("Rate Median Income") +
  ylab("Female Life Growth") +
  guides(shape=guide_legend("Census Region"),
         col=guide_legend("Political Leaning\nof State"))
```

Output:

[image]

Note: You can remove the legends if you'd like. I just included them for educational purposes. To remove the shape legend, for example, use guides(shape=FALSE).

**EDIT: To add the line of best fit to each, try this:**

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Rate_median_income,y=female_life_growth,
                 col=Red_blue,shape=Census_region),size=2.5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=Rate_median_income,y=female_life_growth), 
              method="lm", se=FALSE, col="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ Census_region) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("Blue","Red"),values=c("blue","red")) +
  xlab("Rate Median Income") +
  ylab("Female Life Growth") +
  guides(shape=guide_legend("Census Region"),
         col=guide_legend("Political Leaning\nof State"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Since I have 4 Census Regions, Midwest, West, South, Northeast, how do I modify the code to add these, particularly the "values=c("\u25B2","\u25BC"))" part. I'm not sure what to add for the other 2 regions

Comment: I also keep getting this error when troubleshooting "Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" What does this mean?

Comment: I figured out the error. Since I have so many data points, the resulting graph is kinda tough to view. Do you know how to add lines of best fit for each?

Comment: @JoeJohnson - I saw the added plot in your question. Thanks for adding it. That helps. In case of over-plotting like that, you have a few options. Faceting is one of the most common for this type of case, which I've included an example of above.

Comment: thanks! You answered it so I just marked answered. Can you also help add lines of best fit to each?

Comment: @JoeJohnson - Yes, I'll add this next.